# Passing by reference in a recursive function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using this function to remove undefined properties for an object:

```
function removeUndefinedFromObject(obj) {
    let foundNullProperty = false;
    if (!obj) return obj;
    Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {

        if (obj[key] && typeof obj[key] === "object") {
            foundNullProperty = foundNullProperty || this.removeUndefinedFromObject(obj[key]);
        } else if (obj[key] == null) {
            foundNullProperty = true;
            delete obj[key];
        }
    });
    return foundNullProperty;
}


removeUndefinedFromObject(myObjWithNullValues)
```

I expected all null properties to be removed. However, the values of `myObjWithNullValues` before and after the function call are the same.

So, I have to use this modified version that does what I want:

```
 function removeUndefinedFromObject(obj) {
     let foundNullProperty = false;
     if (!obj) return obj;
     Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {

         if (obj[key] && typeof obj[key] === "object") {
             foundNullProperty = foundNullProperty || this.removeUndefinedFromObject(obj[key]);
         } else if (obj[key] == null) {
             foundNullProperty = true;
             delete obj[key];
         }
     });
     return obj;
 }


 myObjWithNullValues = removeUndefinedFromObject(myObjWithNullValues)
```

My question is why doesn't the first one work? Shouldn't all values of `obj` be passed by reference?

**Edit**

I improved the function to:

```
removeBadValuesFromObject(obj) {
if (!obj || typeof obj !== "object") {
  return obj;
}
Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
  if (obj[key] !== null && typeof obj[key] === "object") {
    this.removeUndefinedFromObject(obj[key]);
  } else if (obj[key] === null || obj[key] === undefined || isNaN(obj[key])) {
    delete obj[key];
  }
});
return obj;
```

}

Comment: *Nothing* is passed by reference in JavaScript. Object "values" are references, but it's strictly a pass-by-value language.

Comment: Also `typeof null` is "object"

Comment: Also also `null` and `undefined` are two different things

Comment: Also, why use this.removeUndefined...? Why not just call the function again directly?

Comment: I remember somewhere I read that in JS objects to methods are *passed-by-sharing*. Also I've copy-pasted your above code snippet to the JS console of the browser and after the method the object was **changed**!
Simply put, the **object** that's passed to the method is changed only if it's properties are modified, which is what you're doing in both code snippets.

Comment: @dashboard I've come to terms with "pass by sharing". The old "pass by value" and "pass by reference" terminology predates modern languages like Java, C#, and JavaScript (and lots of others). Look at how old Fortran worked (and maybe still does) for what old-school "pass by reference" meant.

Comment: Is it just me or can anyone verify that both snippets changes the content after the method ends.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments. Looks like the value I wanted to remove was `NaN`, and not `null`, but showing up as `null` in console, which somehow confused me, and otherwise, both versions do change `obj`. I edited the function to `removeBadValuesFromObject` above.